# Pandas groupby cumulative sum ignore current row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know there's some questions about this topic (like [Pandas: Cumulative sum of one column based on value of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159490/pandas-cumulative-sum-of-one-column-based-on-value-of-another)) however, none of them fuull fill my requirements.

Let's say I have a dataframe like this one

[image: Original dataframe].

I want to compute the cumulative sum of Cost grouping by month, avoiding taking into account the current value, in order to get the Desired column.By using `groupby` and `cumsum` I obtain colum CumSum

[image: Output dataframe].

The DDL to generate the dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [1,1,1,2,2,1,3],
                   'Cost': [5,8,10,1,3,4,1]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
df['agg']=df.groupby('Month')['Cost'].shift().fillna(0)
df['Cumsum']=df['Cost']+df['agg']
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) and then just subtract `cost`;

```
df['cumsum_'] = df.groupby('Month').Cost.cumsum().sub(df.Cost)

print(df)

    Month  Cost  cumsum_
0      1     5        0
1      1     8        5
2      1    10       13
3      2     1        0
4      2     3        1
5      1     4       23
6      3     1        0
```